# Assigning a property with ES6 in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to ES6 and still trying to grasp the concepts of the new specifications, i am currently working on a component in React where i need to make an ajax call and store this response in an object. Then use this object to the map the necessary elements

My component looks like the following

```
export class App extends Component {
    search(){
      //make ajax call
      response = obj.responseText;
    }

    getValues(){}

    render(){
     let result = response.data.map(this.getValues);
     return(
       <div onKeyDown={this.search.bind(this)}>{result}</div>
     )
    }

}
```

How do i declare the "response" variable globally which gets assigned the data from ajax call "obj.responseText"?

Comment: `constructor(){this.response = null;}` after this you put your value in `search(){
      
      this.response = obj.responseText;
    }` maybe?

Comment: You don't want a global variable, you just want an instance property.

Comment: Can you show us how you would've done this in ES5? Btw, ajax is asynchronous, so take that into account.

Comment: @Bergi search(){} is the function that handles the ajax it will be attached to an event handler on one of the elements

Comment: You should definitely read up more about React first: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html .

Comment: Also this doesn't really have anything to do with ES6 but more with React.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you know what you want to achieve, but are a little confused about how to get there.

I would *highly* recommend reading the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html) before you go any further.

#### Why not global variables?

> How do I declare the `response` variable globally?

In short, don't. Global variables are [well-documented as being evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). One instance of this component in a page with a global variable to store its search results would be fine, but imagine if you had two or more instances - they would all share/overwrite each other's search results.

#### Introducing state

Instead, you want to use React's **component state** functionality to store your search results.

You can set an initial state by setting a component's `this.state` in its constructor, (or in ES5, define a `getInitialState` method on the component).

Then, any time you want to update the component's state, you can call its `this.setState(...)` method, passing in a new state object. This will also trigger a re-render of the component.

#### Example

Here is a simple implementation following the above pattern:

```
export class App extends Component {

  // Set the initial state of the component in the constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  // This gets called when your component is mounted
  componentDidMount() {
    // Here we make our AJAX call. I'll leave that up to you
    performMyAjaxMethodDefinedSomewhereElse(result => {

      // We call this method to update `this.state` and trigger re-rendering
      this.setState({ result });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // If we haven't received any results yet, display a message
    if (!this.state.result) {
      return (
        <div>No results!</div>
      );
    }

    // Iterate over the results and show them in a list
    const result = this.state.result.map(text => (<li>{text}</li>));

    // Display the result
    return (
      <ul>{result}</ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Naturally, if you don't want the AJAX call to fire off immediately, you can use a very similar approach, replacing `componentDidMount` with an event handler which looks almost identical.